# Few Questions about the soul and body

Tags: sunni, islamic-philosophy, human-body, soul

Assalamualaikum brothers and sisters,

I am quite curious about the body - soul relationship in human beings. What I wanted to know is :

Can the soul have senses (see, hear, smell, etc.), speak, or move on its own without a body for it to use? Can it think for itself?

Does it depend on the body for such things?

Is the soul self aware/conscious of itself when separated from the body?

If its possible, please provide sources from the Quran, hadiths, or works of muslim scholars.

Jazakhallah khair

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [our] and checking our [help] for more information about this site. This post seems relevant: [What is soul made of as per Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24464/what-is-soul-made-of-as-per-islam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions you ask about *ar-rūḥ* (soul, Arabic: الروح) are similar to the questions that the Prophet ﷺ was asked, and Allah addressed similar questions in the Qur'an:

> وَيَسْأَلُونَكَ عَنِ الرُّوحِ ۖ قُلِ الرُّوحُ مِنْ أَمْرِ رَبِّي وَمَا أُوتِيتُم مِّنَ الْعِلْمِ إِلَّا قَلِيلًا
>
> And they ask you, [O Muhammad], about the soul. Say, "The soul is of the affair of my Lord. And mankind has not been given of knowledge except a little."
>
> <sub>—</sub> [Surat Al-Isra' 17:85](https://quran.com/17/85)

We do not know and no one was given this type of knowledge. Only Allah knows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess we could ask for that knowledge from Allah in the hereafter if we manage to pass this test. Inshallah.